# Changing uniqueness of fields of custom objects?

Tags: appexchange, app, push-upgrade

We have an app on *appexchange* that uses Custom Objects. Today, the logic is changed that some fields of Custom Object have to be unique. How to upgrade existing customers that probably have data duplication of that field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to come up with a data migration policy. You got different possibilities here:

- Delete duplicate records
- Modify them so that they are now unique
- Save the duplicated field to a new, non-unique field

Once you know what to do about it, you need to *implement the data migration in a post install script*, so that when your users upgrade to the new package, the migration will happen automatically.

If you already have one post install script and want to modify it to do data migration, take a look at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104185/is-it-possible-to-add-multiple-post-install-scripts-while-creating-a-manged-pack).

Comment: Mostly correct, but I'm pretty sure the installer would fail because of duplicate entries when the index is created (because it runs after the metadata has been reconfigured). They might need an "intermediate version" that runs the data processing to prepare for the eventual unique index.

Comment: Will the unique index apply retroactively to existing data? I thought it only applied to newly created records...

Comment: Yes, the indexing occurs asynchronously, but does apply to all existing records. There's a check done by the system beforehand that will reject a unique index if more than one record has the same non-blank value.

Comment: Is there any "before-install" script option available? or any other alternatives?